# jQuery - how to animate boxes in the menu?

Tags: jquery, menu

I wanted to make a menu-like thing, consisting of a few boxes, that would float to the side and reveal the link under them, whereas the user moves mouse over them. Here is a fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/txmxn505/1/)

Could you tell me what prevents them from moving?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#kwadrat1").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '-=100px'
        }, slow);
        $("#link1").css("display", "visible");
    });
    $("#kwadrat2").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            top: '-=100px'
        }, slow);
        $("#link2").css("display", "visible");
    });
    $("#kwadrat3").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            bottom: '-=100px'
        }, slow);
        $("#link4").css("display", "visible");
    });
    $("#kwadrat4").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            right: '-=100px'
        }, slow);
        $("#link4").css("display", "visible");
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks fun, but in a real project I'd recommend using CSS transitions for that. or use a css library of effects like http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ or http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another mistake you are doing is that display has no property as visible you should instead use something else like `block`. So:

```
$("#linkX").css("display", "visible");
```

would become:

```
$("#linkX").css("display", "block");
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/txmxn505/3/)</kbd>

According to *Ionică Bizău* suggesstion:

```
$("#linkX").css("display", "block");
```

can become:

```
$("#linkX").show();
```

**Fixed animation:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#kwadrat1").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '-=100'
        }, "slow");
        $("#link1").show();
    });
    $("#kwadrat2").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            top: '-=100'
        }, "slow");
        $("#link2").show();
    });
    $("#kwadrat3").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            top: '+=100'
        }, "slow");
        $("#link3").show();
    });
    $("#kwadrat4").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '+=100'
        }, "slow");
        $("#link4").show();
    });
});
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/txmxn505/6/)

**Changes I made:**

1. Convert the `.css("display")` to `.show()`
2. Remove the `right` and `bottom` properties because there aren't any such only `left` and `top` are used with a variable sign, `left: +=` for moving right and vice versa, `top: +=` for moving bottom and vice versa.
3. Changed `slow` to `"slow"`

Answer (score 2):

When you have such issues, you always have to check browser dev tools console.

In this case you're getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: slow is not defined
```

So, instead of `slow` you have to use `"slow"`.

```
$(this).animate({
    top: '-=100px'
}, "slow");
// ^-- As string instead of variable
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/txmxn505/2/)

Comment: Ah, I was just gonna answer that :/ Anyways. :P

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui You can vote up the post. :-)